# SQL query extremely slow in Kohana web app on EasyPHP win7 server

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, easyphp

I have an EasyPHP local web server with Apache, PHP and MySQL. Until now I've been working with a database that only has 500 records. Sometimes while querying the database there would be a big delay, maybe about 10 seconds, before the data would be returned, but it wasn't consistent. Maybe every 10th user search it would happen. Today I loaded a bunch of test data into 6 tables. Each table now has about 15,000 records. Now, while searching users, it takes about 25 seconds for the data to be returned and happens every time.

Here is the SELECT query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS criteria.id, criteria.uid
FROM user_profile
INNER JOIN criteria ON (criteria.id = user_profile.cid)
WHERE ((criteria.city = 250)
  AND (user_profile.dob BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('1978-09-27', '%Y-%m-%d')
  AND STR_TO_DATE('1993-09-27', '%Y-%m-%d'))
  AND (criteria.gender = 2)
  AND (EXISTS(SELECT id FROM criteria_interests
              WHERE cid = user_profile.cid AND value = 1)
       OR EXISTS(SELECT id FROM criteria_interests
                 WHERE cid = user_profile.cid AND value = 2)))
  AND (user_profile.uid != 2)
LIMIT 0, 18
```

That query takes about 25 seconds to return 202 results. If I run that query inside phpMyAdmin it loads instantly.

I'm not sure where the holdup is. I know that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` can soemtimes cause slowdowns, but not 25 seconds to return 202 rows. Something is wrong here.

I'm wondering how I can track down the problem. The intermittent delay I mentioned first happened basically since I installed EasyPHP, so I thought it was a problem with EasyPHP. But now seeing how much worse the problem has gotten with more database records, I thought it was a MySQL problem. However, when I run the query inside phpMyAdmin, it's very fast. So now I'm thinking it's a PHP issue.

My PHP memory limit is set to 128M, which might not be a lot but that wouldn't cause a 25 second delay.

Does anybody know how I might go about solving this issue? I'm not the most knowledgable when it comes to configuring Apache, PHP, or MySQL, so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you try the [Kohana profiler](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/profiling). That will at least identify if your looking in the right place. Also make sure you have correctly specified your indexes in MySql and look into enabling the [Mysql slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: I didn't know about the profiler! That lead me straight to the problem query, which was actually the COUNT() select right after the search results select. Thank you for that. That basically answered my question, so if you put that in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with loading from database. It runs extremely slow on my EasyPHP local environment. However, when I have uploaded it on remote hosting server problem was already gone. So if your EasyPHP runs your application slowly, don't worry too much, it will run OK on real server.

If you really can't handle this lag wile developing locally use XAMPP environment instead.
Download link:
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found solution for your problem. This might not address the particular issue but it might resolve it anyway.
Your question made me think what can I do to fix this issue ... and this may sound rather not comfortable, but i just fixed it by installing wamp server:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Now you probably say ... "Hey you said you have fixed it not change the development server"

And yes ! Once I have installed wamp server and after I have applied to it above mysql configuration shown on youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ob7Rvzobec&noredirect=1

my **EasyPHP** got a massive **boost of speed!** Now it work like a charm. The query from database are quick as hell. And from this place I would like to remind you that I faced exactly same issue as yours. Now the problem is solved and my EasyPHP can shine again.

Maybe this will also solve your problem. Good luck! :)